# What is the good software to watch live stream (.ogg file) from the internet, on Macbook?

Tags: streaming

What is the good software to watch live stream (.ogg file) from the internet, on Macbook? I tried VLC player, but it doesn't work for http://www.b92.net/tv/uzivo.php .What can you recommend?

Comment: They (the link you provided) reccomends VLC. Have you tried asking them?   You can also try [FFMPEG](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide)  I use it to record OTA radio to turn into personal podcasts, but you can re-broadcast from it.  See the link I provided.

Comment: I need to download (watch) the stream, not to upload (make) one.

Comment: FFMpeg does that.  Your input would be the stream, your output is anything you want, a video file, a stream, whatever.  Point is, FFMPEG allows you to convert from your incompatible stream to something that will work for you.